# Binding to a Command from a DataTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

firstly thanks in advance for any help.

I have an application that i want to add a Navigation menu into. I have created a DataTemplate that has all my buttons and styling and I currently have that in my stylesheet.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Navigation">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="0" Columns="1">
            <Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Menu, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" >Page 1</Button>
            <Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Menu, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" >Page 2</Button>
            <Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Menu, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" >Page 3</Button>
            <Button Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Menu, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" >Page 4</Button>
        </UniformGrid>
        <ToggleButton Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ToggleBtnToolStyle}" x:Name="Menu" IsChecked="true" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ContentPresenter Margin="5" Height="50" Content="{StaticResource MenuIcon}"></ContentPresenter>
                <Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource TxtToolStyle}">Menu</TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Currently the only way i have been able to get this working is to remove it from the DataTemplate and implement the grid on each page.
Is there a way of binding to my NavigationViewModel from my DataTemplate that is stored in my Stylesheet?
I'm sorry if this question is badly worded, I'm new to WPF and can do the basic data binding but I'm lost here.

Thanks

Edit

The ViewModel with the Commands i would like to link to looks like this

```
public abstract class NavigationViewModelBase : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<DicomMetadataModel> _dicomMetadata;


    //Navigation Cmd
    public ICommand AcquisitionPageCmd { get; private set; }
    public ICommand ManualEntryWindowCmd { get; private set; }
    public ICommand SessionWindowCmd { get; private set; }
    public ICommand SettingsWindowCmd { get; private set; }
    public ICommand StudyInfoPageCommandCmd { get; private set; }
    public ICommand ViewerPageCmd { get; private set; }
    public ICommand WorklistPageCmd { get; private set; }


    protected NavigationViewModelBase()
    {
        AcquisitionPageCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Messenger.Default.Send(new GoToPageMessage(Pages.AcquisitionScreen)));
        ManualEntryWindowCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Messenger.Default.Send(new ShowDialogMessage(Pages.ManualEntry, DicomMetadata)));
        SessionWindowCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Messenger.Default.Send(new ShowDialogMessage(Pages.Session)));
        SettingsWindowCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Messenger.Default.Send(new ShowDialogMessage(Pages.Settings)));
        ViewerPageCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Messenger.Default.Send(new GoToPageMessage(Pages.Viewer)));
        WorklistPageCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Messenger.Default.Send(new GoToPageMessage(Pages.Worklist)));
    }
}
```

}

And them in every page i would like to add the Navigation Menu into the code will look like this

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Navigation }" />
```

Comment: What command are you trying to bind to what control?

Comment: I want to go to another page so the current command i have is ViewerPageCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Messenger.Default.Send(new GoToPageMessage(Pages.Viewer)));

Comment: At the moment i am just calling Command="{Binding ViewerPageCmd"} but this has to be declared in the viewmodel where the control is added. I would like to cut down on having to add these commands in each viewmodel

Comment: You can have viewmodel base and each viewmodel can inherit the command from the base. Then you would only have one command.

Comment: That would work perfectly, the only issue is that i am using MVVM Light so  I am already inheriting from that to use the Observable collections and other stuff that comes with that.

Comment: @ColmClarke Thats not an issue, you can create your own base class, which will inherit from MVVM Light class, and then you will use your new class. It should work exactly the same way as it is now.

Comment: @adminSoftDK Thank you so much, I should have seen that, I can't see the wood for the trees at the moment lol Thanks for all your hep

Comment: @adminSoftDK is it possible to bind to these commands from my current setup where the datatemplate is store in the stylesheet.xaml?

Comment: I don't see why not, you would have to post your viewmodel as well, and tell people what this template is used for, so we can see the bigger picture. It is possible that this datatemplate is used inside listbox, then your itemssource is observablecollection of some kind, but your command is on the viewmodel itself, then you have to do relativesource binding. But this is all just guessing, because I don't see what you actually created. Please post your viewmodel, and that part of xaml which is using this datatemplate.